# How to natural join and then selecting from this table in SQL oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, natural-join

I have a table with the following attributes:

```
 Table1(tid, p_name, country)
 Table2(pid1, pid2, match_start, goals1, goals2)
```

Where I have inserted some random values.

> Find the names of all players from Bolivia that have played against a
>   player from India. Make sure no duplicate names are returned.

I have been thinking to do like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p_name
FROM Table1 NATURAL JOIN Table2
WHERE (
         (Table1.tid = Table2.pid1 or 
          Table1.tid = Table2.pid2 and 
           Table1.country = 'India') and 
       Table1.country = 'Bolivia')
```

And I get a table with all the p_names that are connected to the country Bolivia, but I cant make it give me the players that ONLY have been played against a player from India. I dont want the players that haven't been playing against India

Can someone help me to fix my problem? Im I completely wrong?

Comment: Can you please describe the columns in the two tables? What are pid1 and pid2? Also, in that query, what are the common columns that you are 'natural join'ing on?

Comment: pid1 are player id for the player that player for the first team (home-team).
pid2 are player id for the player that player for the second team (away-team).

Comment: Why do you have Oracle and MySQL and SQL-Server all tagged?   Are you using all three?

Comment: I don't know why I tapped mysql. Edited*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're completely wrong.

The NATURAL JOIN is pointless: there are no column names in common between Table1, Table2 -- as ruudvan questioned. You might as well have

FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE ...

To tackle this you need in effect to get two copies of Table1 -- one for the home team (with tid = pid1), one for the away team (with tid = pid2). Then filter for matches Bolivia at home to India OR India at home to Bolivia. Then project p_name from the Bolivian teams. (That'll be two sets of p_name from the home and away matches.) UNION DISTINCT the two sets.

Answer (score 0):

I would construct this with an EXISTS correlated subquery because what you actually want is a list of players for whom the country is 'Bolivia' for which there exists a match against the team 'India'.

Your data model is not clear to me, and it's probably simplified, as I'd expect to see a table for the teams, a table for the players, a table for the matches, and a table for the role that each player took in the match ('played', 'substitute not used', 'substitute used', that sort of thing).

You should always be suspicious of a need to perform a DISTINCT operation on a query. I'm not saying that it is always incorrect, but it often points to a problem with the data model, or a method of compensating for a poorly structured query.

Comment: In this case, I expect the DISTINCT p_name is needed: each Bolivian player will typically have played in more than one match against India. (But I do agree that the data model seems over-simplified. In particular, I'd like to know the keys for each table.)

Comment: But my point is that it wouldn't be needed if for each Bolivian player you are looking for the existence of any match against India using EXISTS, because you are not joining to every instance of a match against India.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat different approach.

Get two copies of Table1, one for Bolivia, one for India. Then filter for Bolivia at home to India (B.tid = pid1 and I.tid = pid2) or Bolivia away to India (B.tid = pid2 and I.tid = pid1). Project on the Bolivia p_name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.p_name
FROM Table1 B, Table2, Table1 I
WHERE B.country = 'Bolivia'
  AND I.country = 'India'
  AND (   (B.tid = pid1 AND I.tid = pid2)
       OR (B.tid = pid2 AND I.tid = pid1)
      )
```